# Is it possible to use a cell reference as row/column positions in getRange()?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, inventory

I am trying to make a button in a spreadsheet inventory that would rapidly add the right item in the right column of my inventory. I have a sheet dedicated to this button where you select the product to add to the inventory, then click GO and your item goes into one of the 10 columns of my inventory (depending on which item it is) along with quantity and a tag number. The selections in the list are associated  with their number of items per pallet for a full pallet and the row number in which they should go in the inventory on a table on another sheet. I use the filter function to display both these informations on the button sheet so that when you press the button the displayed information is copied to the inventory using this line of script:

```
 var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Fiche");
 var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
 var source = ss.getRange ('A3');
var destColumn = ss.getRange ('B15');

source.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, destColumn), {contentsOnly: true});
```

Where A3 is my amount of product on a full pallet and B15 is the column in which it should be copied. It seems that using variable lastRow is okay for  giving getRange its row position but variable destColumn doesn't work for column position. It only works when I replace it with a constant number. I guess the type of data returned from getLastRow and getRange are not the same? any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close to the solution. You only need to add [`.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) at the end of the `var destColumn = ss.getRange ('B15');` so it reads the number inside the cell (because the method [`.getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) used later works with integers as detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#parameters_21)). The final result should look like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  /*var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    "{SPREADSHEET ID}");*/
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Fiche");
  var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
  var source = ss.getRange('A3');
  var destColumn = ss.getRange('B15').getValues();

  source.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, destColumn), {
    contentsOnly: true
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer! I tested your solution but it does not seem to work. The button works but it does not send my copyTo to the right column. In my test, the value in B15 is 6 and when i press the button, it copies my data to column 2 (or B) while i would want it to go in column 6. I think your piece of code getColumn grabs the column in which B15 is located (therefore always B). Am I right?

Comment: You are totally right @SimonThibert! I am strongly ashamed of misunderstanding your question, please forgive me. I have just updated my answer to fulfill your goals.

Comment: No need to be ashamed! I've been struggling with this problem for about 3 hours right before i decided to post here. My brain felt like a cauliflower when i wrote my question so it might be my fault if it was a bit unclear. You might want to edit the code section of your answer as well for people who will consult this topic in the future. Will be trying your new solution as soon as i come home tonight.

Comment: Hi there @SimonThibert! I just updated the code, excuse me for forgetting it. If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/589350) by clicking the checkmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.